# LSTM Time series output not match to the actual data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I use LSTM model in Keras to predict time series data. I use MinMaxScaler to normalize data and create model like this code.

```
sc = MinMaxScaler()
train_sc = sc.fit_transform(train)
test_sc = sc.transform(test)

X_train = train_sc[:-1]
y_train = train_sc[1:]

X_test = test_sc[:-1]
y_test = test_sc[1:]

X_train_t = X_train[:, None]
X_test_t = X_test[:, None]

K.clear_session()
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(12, input_shape=(1, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train_t, y_train,epochs=200, batch_size=1, verbose=1)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test_t)

real_pred = sc.inverse_transform(y_pred)
real_test = sc.inverse_transform(y_test)
```

The output show like this image. when put test value in model.predict() then it show predict value. So, I think predict value should compare to the next test value like this table.

[image]

The picture show that the predicted value is not match to the actual value. It look like output copy value from input to show. How to fix it?

Comment: I don't find any problem.. the bias is because the predicted values are in a shift of 1, move them up 1 cell.

Comment: Yes, Inline with above comment , The prediction is a similar ,but not exact copy of  actual results . Prediction looks fine to me ,Just saw a shift in cell in spreadsheet. Thanks!